# org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 0

Tags: java, android

When i register it stores the data but doenot show any messages.
Here is my register.java

```java
 private void registerUser(final String name, final String email,
                              final String password,final String phoneNumber,final String UserType) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_register";

        pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
        showDialog();

        Log.d(TAG, "it is done!");
// (It says error on this line:)
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();
                 Log.d(TAG, "user added");

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response.substring(14));
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Register Response-error: " + error);
```

Please help me

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs as a result of `response.substring(14)` code part providing an invalid json.

I would use this code to converst String to Standard  Json.

```
public String convertToStandardJSONString(String data_json) {
        data_json = data_json.replaceAll("\\\\r\\\\n", "");
        data_json = data_json.replace("\"{", "{");
        data_json = data_json.replace("}\",", "},");
        data_json = data_json.replace("}\"", "}");
        return data_json;
    }
```

Try to pass `response.substring(14)` to above function, and use the returned value.

```
JSONObject jObj = newJSONObject(convertStandardJSONString(response.substring(14)));
```